# send binary form-data in golang

Tags: post, go, multipartform-data

I have the headers down for my post request, but I don't know how to send the data in binary and compressed. This is my curl command:

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.90:333/sendMessage.srv' 
-H 'Origin: http://192.168.1.90:333' 
-H 'Accept-Encocding: gzip, deflate' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryycti6tczDNAO3xqF' 
-H 'Accept: */*' 
-H 'Referer: http://192.168.1.90:333/' 
-H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--data-binary PAYLOAD --compressed
```

this is my payload that I am trying to send

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryycti6tczDNAO3xqF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hashid"
+12223334444
------WebKitFormBoundaryycti6tczDNAO3xqF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reqUID"
wxyz
------WebKitFormBoundaryycti6tczDNAO3xqF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipients"
------WebKitFormBoundaryycti6tczDNAO3xqF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-name"
------WebKitFormBoundaryycti6tczDNAO3xqF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"
message
------WebKitFormBoundaryycti6tczDNAO3xqF--
```

or on 1 line it is

```
$'------WebKitFormBoundaryk7s3ZvI9evAhMsEL\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="hashid"\r\n\r\n+12223334444\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryk7s3ZvI9evAhMsEL\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="reqUID"\r\n\r\nly9a\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryk7s3ZvI9evAhMsEL\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="recipients"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryk7s3ZvI9evAhMsEL\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file-name"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryk7s3ZvI9evAhMsEL\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="text"\r\n\r\nmessage\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryk7s3ZvI9vAhMsEL--\r\n'
```

and this is my code:

```
body := strings.NewReader(`$------WebKitFormBoundaryU8vOdhYkInm8YBuZ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="hashid"\r\n\r\n+12223334444\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryU8vOdhYkInm8YBuZ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="reqUID"\r\n\r\nvvpr\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryU8vOdhYkInm8YBuZ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="recipients"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryU8vOdhYkInm8YBuZ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file-name"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryU8vOdhYkInm8YBuZ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="text"\r\n\r\message\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryU8vOdhYkInm8YBuZ--\r\n`)

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://192.168.1.90:333/sendMessage.srv", body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
req.Header.Set("Origin", "http://192.168.1.90:333")
req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36")
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryU8vOdhYkInm8YBuZ")
req.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
req.Header.Set("Referer", "http://192.168.1.90:333/")
req.Header.Set("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
req.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? And why don't you use multipart?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `$` byte at the beginning of your body. Do consider using the [mime/multipart package](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) though.